# Which preposition to use after the word "chaud" in the sense of "avoir envie de"?

Tags: expressions, usage, prépositions

I was watching a [video](https://youtu.be/pB-7dTUJUB8?t=201) on YouTube. I think he said:

> Avant de finir, pour ceux qui seraient **chaud de** tester le concept, n’hésitez pas à m’envoyer vos créations sur Twitter et sur Facebook.

Q1: When I use the word "chaud" like this in the sense of "avoir envie de", I always couple it with the preposition "pour" instead of "de". I wonder if both are acceptable?

Q2: On Wiktionnaire, the "chaud" in this specific sense is tagged as *mélioratif*. Does this "chaud" usage come across as more polite than saying, for instance, "pour ceux qui voudraient tester le concept"?

Answer (score 4):

**Q1: When I use the word "chaud" like this in the sense of "avoir envie de", I always couple it with the preposition "pour" instead of "de". I wonder if both are acceptable?**

The *real* idiom is "chaud pour" and not "chaud de". However "chaud de" is used from time to time, as well as only "chaud":

> T'es **chaud de** faire un bowling?
>
> T'es **chaud** on fait un bowling?

Which are the same as:

> T'es **chaud pour** faire un bowling?

Please note that "chaud de" and "chaud" are less correct than the original idiom "chaud pour". These are oral deformations, you should avoid saying them.

**Q2: On Wiktionnaire, the "chaud" in this specific sense is tagged as mélioratif. Does this "chaud" usage come across as more polite than saying, for instance, "pour ceux qui voudraient tester le concept"?**

Absolutely not! "Chaud" is also labeled "familier". Never use this idiom when you're not talking to someone you're close to (friend, family...). It is "mélioratif" because it encourages the person you're talking too to do what you are suggesting. It adds a positive feeling to your sentence. As an example, this sentence:

> T'es chaud pour un bowling ?

Has a feeling close to:

> [FR] Allez viens on va au bowling !
>
> [EN] Let's go bowling!

And less close to:

> [FR] Tu voudrais aller au bowling ?
>
> [EN] Would you want to go bowling?

Comment: Excellent explanation! :D How does "*Et si on allait faire un bowling?*" compare to "*T'es chaud pour faire un bowling?*" Does the former come across as a milder suggestion?

Comment: *Et si on allait faire un bowling* is fairly standard in informal French, whereas *t'es chaud pour un bowling* i a fairly recent usage of the adjective *chaud*, so it would be used mainly by speakers, say, under 30 (in my own personal experience as father of 2 teenagers, that is the kind of phrases I hear them using 10 times a day, but if I use it, they will roll their eyes at me).

Comment: As Greg said, "*Et si on allait faire un bowling ?*" is more polite, like "*Tu voudrais aller au bowling ?*". The first is more "mélioratif" than the latter, it sounds more like a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:** You can say both "chaud de" and "chaud pour", it's understandable by a french speaker because...

**Q2:** ...it's really, really informal! You would better use "avoir envie de" or "vouloir" instead of "être chaud de/pour".